# How can I login here when OpenID stops without losing my current information?

Tags: discussion, login, openid

I am using Google Account OpenId to login here. However, I have been notified that Google Account OpenId will stop next year.

What should I do now? I do not want to lose my current information. So create a brand new account is not what I want.

Edit - Verisign are also stopping this year. OpenId users should probably check their provider

Comment: Go to your profile, find "my logins" in the toolbar, then hit "add more logins..." to add more login options.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get a standalone account without any OpenId accounts connecting with?

Comment: @OwenZhao Stack Exchange is built completely on top of OpenID, but you can use [Stack Exchange's](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) own Open ID, which should always work with Stack Exchange.

Comment: @vcsjones Actually you method does not work. I logout this account and create a new stack exchange OpenId. I have to logout or there is no register button shows. Then I logout the stack exchange OpenId and re-login with the current one. I try to add the stack exchange OpenId to this one. It does not work. The website will automatically logout the current account and login the stack exchange one. So I can not merge them together.

Comment: @OwenZhao There's a way to request a merge of the two, since it seems to have made two individual accounts on you. [See this page in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to go about that. It's a rather easy process, looks like. :)

Comment: Wont Google still have OpenID options via Google+ and other services? And you should be able to either convert to the new format.

Comment: Thank you, @Kendra . I have tried you suggestion. I hope it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Sad to see that everyone is abandoning OpenID.

Comment: @JoeW is right. Google is shutting down *OpenID* and makes *Google+ Sign-In* and *OAuth 2.0* available. If you simple upgrate to that you'll be able to keep your profile. You won't need a Google+ Profile but it will require that StackOverflow firstly updates it's authentication method or migrates to Google+ Sign-In. [Here more information](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#sign-in)

Answer (score 1):

1 Thanks to @vcsjones in the above comments, logout your current Google Account OpenId, and create a new Stack Exchange OpenId. Activate your Stack Exchange OpenId by click the link Stack Exchange sending to your email.

2 Thanks to @Kendra in the above comments, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) can merge your accounts. You just need to get the two links of your Google Account OpenId and Stack Exchange OpenId. Say that you want them to merge. The website will send you two email to verify each of the account. Then both of them are merged together.